# javax.mail error when parsing email address header with '[' character

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to digest some messages coming in via a gmail account and one or more messages I receive have a formatted name in the header for the sender.  Something along the lines of

`[hris [hristerson <chrisDoesNotExist@gmail.com>`

The name above is fake, but illustrates the scenario I'm encountering, the name is replacing one or more 'C' characters with '['.

The code that triggers the error

```
String header = "[hris [hristerson <chrisDoesNotExist@gmail.com>";
boolean strict = true; // I also tried using a false value
InternetAddress.parse(header, strict);
```

The error itself manifests as: `javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Missing ']'`

Some research I was doing was making me think that using encoded-words per RFC-2047 might be an answer.  But unless I was attempting it incorrectly, it didn't appear to work.  Additionally, other similarly illegal characters don't give me the same error per my testing, which makes me think that it's incidental, and is more uniquely a java library problem.

The code that I used to attempt a rudimentary encoded-word fix was:

```
public String encodePrettyEmailHeader(String header, String charset, char encoding) {

    Map<String, String> illegalChars = new HashMap<>();

    illegalChars.put("\\[", "=5B");
    illegalChars.put("]", "=5D");
    illegalChars.put("\\(", "=28");
    illegalChars.put("\\);", "=29");
    illegalChars.put("<", "=3C");
    illegalChars.put(">", "=3E");
    illegalChars.put("@", "=40");
    illegalChars.put(",", "=2C");
    illegalChars.put(";", "=3B");
    illegalChars.put(":", "=3A");
    illegalChars.put("\"", "=22");
    illegalChars.put("/", "=2F");
    illegalChars.put("\\?", "=3F");
    illegalChars.put(" ", "=20");

    String email = getEmailFromHeader(header).trim(); // regex to get the <email@address.com> from the header
    String name = header.substring(0, header.indexOf(email)).trim();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> anEntry : illegalChars.entrySet()) {
        name = name.replaceAll(anEntry.getKey(), anEntry.getValue());
    }

    return String.format("=?%s?%c?%s?= %s", charset, encoding, name, email);
}
```

Calling it like: `InternetAddress.parse(encodePrettyEmailHeader(header, "UTF-8", 'Q'), strict);`

I'm hoping that there is an answer that doesn't involve manually encoding the data into quoted-printable, I believe I should be able to make this janky solution work, however, this will add more overhead since I will need to un-encode it before the data can be usefully displayed.

Does anyone have any advice for me to proceed?

Edit:

I upgraded my version and the same result happened.  However, I realized that when I obfuscated the address header, I added an additional set of quotes beyond what arrives from gmail.  For brevity:

This is how I incorrectly formatted it:
`"[hris [hristerson" <chrisDoesNotExist@gmail.com>`

This is the correct format that fails for me:
`[hris [hristerson <chrisDoesNotExist@gmail.com>`

Edit 2:

For clarity, I'm using `group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.5.5'` and I've made the upgrade to `group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.0'` with no difference in behavior.

I've also tried setting strict to false, but the exception thrown is no different.[image: Debugger screenshot example]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using exactly the code you have above with JavaMail 1.6.0.  What version of JavaMail are you using?

Comment: Ah!  That's interesting, I appear to be using 1.5.5.  This may be worth looking into to see if it's a version error

Comment: I upgraded my javamail version to 1.6.0 and I'm about to start testing.  I will report back @BillShannon

Comment: @BillShannon I appended my question with some new details.  I apologize for not scrutinizing my data better

Comment: It's clearly a bogus address.  Set the Session property [`mail.mime.address.strict`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html#mail.mime.address.strict) to false.

Comment: @BillShannon I tried setting the `strict` flag to false, however, I get the same exception thrown.  Nothing appears to be different.  I tried this using both 1.5.5 and 1.6.0.

Comment: If you're calling InternetAddress.parse directly (which you shouldn't need to do if you're processing messages from a mail server), you need to instead call InternetAddress.parseHeader; the property tells the MimeMessage class to do that.  If it still doesn't work, show me a test case.

Comment: I didn't realize that, I'll do that and if it doesn't work as expected, I'll write up a junit test that can stand alone (assuming javamail dependency is already resolved) and append it to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions for you.

1) Using constructor:

```
InternetAddress workingStyle2 = new InternetAddress("chrisDoesNotExist@gmail.com", "[hris [hristerson","UTF-8");
System.out.println(workingStyle2.getPersonal());
System.out.println(workingStyle2.getAddress());
```

2) Using **strict** mode = *false*. Note the different API when you use strict mode, call [parseHeader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#parseHeader(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) instead of just parse.

> To better support the range of "invalid" addresses seen in real messages, this method enforces fewer syntax rules than the parse method when the strict flag is false and enforces more rules when the strict flag is true. If the strict flag is false and the parse is successful in separating out an email address or addresses, the syntax of the addresses themselves is not checked.

```
    boolean strict = false;
    InternetAddress[] working = InternetAddress.parseHeader(header, strict);
    System.out.println(working[0].getPersonal());
    System.out.println(working[0].getAddress());
```

Comment: Option 2 appears to have done it for me!  Headers that contain that problematic character successfully parses when using a combination of `strict=false` and `InternetAddress.parseHeader(...)`